# Random records, but maximal one from each category

Tags: mysql

I would like get 3 random stamps, but each from different country. This query return random stamps, but could be from the same country. When I add GROUP BY country_id I will get 3 stamps of different countries, but only first stamps of each country.

```
SELECT `stamps`.`stamp_id`, `countries`.`country_name_cs` FROM `stamps`
LEFT JOIN `countries` ON countries.country_id = stamps.country_id
WHERE (stamps.stamp_enabled = 1) ORDER BY rand() ASC LIMIT 3
```

Any idea?

Query profile (#Ezequiel Muns solution)

```
starting              0.000232
Opening tables        0.000047
System lock           0.000013
Table lock            0.000635
optimizing            0.000036
statistics            0.000022
preparing             0.000023
Creating tmp table    0.000293
executing             0.000004
Copying to tmp table  0.060066
Sorting result        0.013835
Sending data          0.089164
removing tmp table    0.000632
Sending data          0.000026
init                  0.000048
optimizing            0.000014
statistics            0.000061
preparing             0.000028
Creating tmp table    0.000326
executing             0.000004
Copying to tmp table  0.353176
Sorting result        0.000158
Sending data          0.000038
end                   0.000005
removing tmp table    0.000018
end                   0.000006
query end             0.000004
freeing items         0.000575
removing tmp table    0.002363
closing tables        0.000023
logging slow query    0.000004
cleaning up           0.000009

id      select_type       table      type       possible_keys       key         key_len     ref           rows      Extra
1       PRIMARY       <derived2>     ALL        NULL                NULL        NULL        NULL          12679     Using temporary; Using filesort
1       PRIMARY       c              eq_ref     PRIMARY             PRIMARY     4           s.country_id  1      
2       DERIVED       stamps         ALL        NULL                NULL        NULL        NULL          12679     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: If you are willing to put some time in it, here is a page that explains an efficient way to do this : http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: Hi Ilanco, I can't apply on my example. Could you help me to figure out please?

Comment: This isn't really surprising, and there's nothing an index anywhere can do, because like I said, the ORDER BY RAND() needs to read the whole table (even if the column you're selecting is indexed, go figure). The only other solution is to use PHP (or another application language) to choose 3 random country id's, and then one random stamp for each.

Comment: But how can I choose three countries by PHP. PHP don't know which ids are in database (some id can be deleted). Even if I have got that ids, will use ORDER BY RAND() to get random stamp of country, won't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following query, this selects 3 random countries first, performs a join with a mixed stamp table, and then groups by country. Not efficient, but workable for smaller data sets.

```
 SELECT
    mixed_stamp.stamp_id,
    random.country_name_cs
 FROM
    (SELECT * FROM stamps ORDER BY RAND()) AS mixed_stamp
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT country_id FROM countries ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) random ON (random.country_id = mixed_stamp.country_id)
 GROUP BY random.country_id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    c.country_id,
    c.country_name_cs,
    s.stamp_id
FROM country c
    JOIN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM stamps
        WHERE stamp_enabled = 1
        ORDER BY RAND()
    ) AS s ON c.country_id = s.country_id
GROUP BY c.country_id, c.country_name_cs
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3;
```

You first join all countries to their respective stamps but in a random order, then the group by trims that list to the first (randomly chosen) stamp for each country. The outer query's ORDER BY randomises the country you choose, and then LIMIT returns just 3.

Like David Z said, inefficient.

Comment: And is something more efficient? It will work with hundred of tousands records.

Comment: I don't actually know, you'd have to test for yourself with that amount of data. It may end up being bearable. 
It's inefficient because ORDER BY RAND() always scans the whole table.

For better efficiency, I would do the randomization in the application code rather than in the DBMS using SQL, but that would be a different question all together.

Comment: I tested on 13 tousands records and query works good, but durate half second. It is about 10 times slower than my query (query profile is up). I think, that with more records it will be worst and worst. So how improve it? Problem is only with random sort on table stamps (not countries).

Comment: Can you paste the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` as well to see the query plan?

Comment: Is it pasted below my origin post.

Comment: That isn't a query plan, that's a profile. Write:
`EXPLAIN SELECT
    c.country_id,
    c.country_name_cs,
    s.stamp_id
FROM country c
    JOIN (
        SELECT * 
        FROM stamps
        WHERE stamp_enabled = 1
        ORDER BY RAND()
    ) AS s ON c.country_id = s.country_id
GROUP BY c.country_id, c.country_name_cs
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3`
and post what you get back.